# Real Analysis: Covergence Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $( x_n )$ is a sequence of real numbers, $( y_n )$ is a bounded sequence of non-zero real numbers, and that $\lim x_n/ y_n = 1$. Prove that $\lim (x_n - y_n) = 0$.
Since $y_n$ is bounded, there exist M such that $\vert y_n \vert \le M$ for all $n \in N$. Then what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use $x_n - y_n = y_n(\frac{x_n}{y_n} - 1)$.

Comment: Could you show more?

Comment: $|x_n - y_n| = |y_n(\frac{x_n}{y_n} - 1)| \leq M|\frac{x_n}{y_n} - 1|$.

Comment: how does this show that xn−yn →0.?

Comment: @ afsdf dfsaf: since, $\dfrac{x_n}{y_n}\to 1$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by John, $(y_n)$ is bounded and $(\dfrac{x_n}{y_n}-1)$ converges to $0$, therefore, $x_n-y_n\to 0$.

Comment: just to claify xn−yn→0 means lim(xn−yn)=0?

Comment: yes@ afsdf dfsaf